# Why are my maps out of order now?

Tags: starcraft-2

The other day I played a custom map in StarCraft II.  Now my maps are out of order.  When I go to play vs the AI, my maps used to be sorted by number of players then name, but now they appear to be in a completely random order, and the default settings are Custom.  Why did this happen?  How can I fix it (short of reinstalling the game or something)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't there a way to change the sorting? by clicking the column heads?

Comment: In that case this is a really good question.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in patch 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure as to what this problem was caused by, it seems to have been fixed as of Patch 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the maps sorted by their current usage through Battle.Net? Thought that I lastly have seen that they are sorted like "currently most played". Maybe this is why your order is different to the day before?